# Character ñ in basque language

Tags: characters, tilde

I'm trying to put the character ñ with basque language.
I've seen that in some languages you can use `\~{n}` but it doesn't work.
I need to put it in the text format, not like `$\tilde{n}$`.
Can someone help me?

I have this error message: `LaTeX Error: Command \texttilde unavailable in encoding T1.`

The error appears when I add `\usepackage{hyperref}`

I can see questions about putting ~ symbol but not how to put the spanish character ñ.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{basque-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[basque]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document} españa \end{document}
```

Error free log from texlive 2022

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.12.4)  21 DEC 2022 10:20
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**dd147
(./dd147.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/basque-book/basque-book.cls
Document Class: basque-book 2012/07/06 v1.20 Standard LaTeX document class adap
ted to Basque
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/basque-date/basque-date.sty
Package: basque-date 2012/05/15 v1.05 basque-date Package
\c@urtea=\count185
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo
File: bk11.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count186
\c@chapter=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\c@figure=\count193
\c@table=\count194
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\@contcwidth=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2022/11/30 3.83 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count195
\U@D=\dimen141
\l@unhyphenated=\language87

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count196

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-basque/basque.ldf
Language: basque 2005/03/29 v1.0f Basque support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 85.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/eu/babel-basque.te
x
Package babel Info: Importing font and identification data for basque
(babel)             from babel-eu.ini. Reported on input line 11.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-10-26 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count197
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (./dd147.aux)
\openout1 = `dd147.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
 [1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

] (./dd147.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1723 strings out of 474968
 29366 string characters out of 5776089
 384723 words of memory out of 5000000
 23280 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 471154 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 40i,5n,52p,171b,149s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/c
m-super-t1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/
sfrm1095.pfb>
Output written on dd147.pdf (1 page, 14316 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: You can use  `ñ`  or `\~{n}`

Comment: Using that appears n, not ñ

Comment: You are doing something wrong but if you do not show your code or your error message we can not help You should get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lles0.png) from `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[basque]{babel}
\begin{document}
woñrds wo\~{n}rds wo\~nrds
\end{document}`

Comment: I have this:  ` \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{basque-book} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[basque]{babel} \begin{document} españa \end{document}` and my error message is: `LaTeX Error: Command \texttilde unavailable in encoding T1.`

Comment: Something in `basque-book.cls` is messing up the font ecnoding definition.

Comment: Your example [makes this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRWSE.png) in a current latex, show your log file

Comment: The `basque-book` manual says that the document class is incompatible with `babel`. Does commenting out the `babel` package (or using the `shorthands-off` option) fix it?

Comment: @Davislor ooh a manual:-) Can you reproduce the OP's error?

Comment: @Irati I added the log file from texlive 2022, can you add your log, so we can compare

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cannot reproduce it, no. In another comment, OP says there are two additional packages not included in the MWE.

Comment: @Davislor "not included in the MWE. " sigh:-)

Comment: @Irati you have edited the example to add hyperref but that has no effect on the document ñ works as intended. Do as you are asking us to do copy the example from your question to a new file and check it shows the problem. If it does, then you have a broken tex installation but if, as already requested, you show the full log, someone could debug.

Comment: Appears to work correctly here, as well (LuaLaTeX 1.15.0, TeX Live 2022).

Answer (score 4):

**ETA:** From your comments, what’s actually happening is that a package you did not list in your MWE is buggy.

#### Original Answer

On LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, add the line `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

On PDFLaTeX, add the line, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead.  (On some old distributions, from before 2018, you might additionally need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage{textcomp}`, but on modern ones, you don’t.)

You can now type either ñ or `\~{n}`.

That will probably do everything you need, but if you want the main language of the document to be Basque, you can additionally add:

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off, basque]{babel}
```

Your error message suggests you’re loading some package that messes up the definition of this character.

Comment: even with OT1 `ñ` should work for display. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
ñ
\end{document}`  with no package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Also, the error message mentions the T1 encoding.

Comment: OP added that later, but then that means they are already using T1 so adding `On PDFLaTeX, add the line, \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`  will do nothing

Comment: I don´t understand well what are you speaking about. The template i'm using is this: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14oJyDaMvJ7G0c0McLdXVR_zHkBsH21O8?usp=sharing i think the error is in TFG.sty or in Memoria.tex

Comment: @Irati Okay, neither of those packages are in your MWE. Can you please edit your question to give a MWE that actually reproduces the bug?

Comment: @Davislor I have discovered that it works but the error appears when adding \usepackage{hyperref}. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Irati What would really help us help you is if you could post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that reproduces the bug. Otherwise, we can’t tell whether anything we do fixes it. My first guess, though, would be: take out `babel` and load `hyperref` last.

Comment: @Davislor I'll study how to post a MWE thanks! Changing the order to charge the packages it works! Thanks u :)